# Eager execution in tensorflow custom estimators

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm rewriting my code using custom Estimator logic, and I need to enable eager execution to get the metrics/predictions I need. However, it seems that enabling eager execution does not go through for some reason. To reproduce, I can use the example located at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/iris.py with some prints:

```
...
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
...
def my_model(features, labels, mode):
  print("IS EAGER? (my_model) - {}".format(tf.executing_eagerly()))
...
print("IS EAGER? - {}".format(tf.executing_eagerly()))
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=my_model)
```

Which results in the following when I run the script:

```
IS EAGER? - True
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
...
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
IS EAGER? (my_model) - False
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
```

How do I get my model to execute eagerly? I'm using tensorflow 1.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Estimator` API is pretty tightly tied to graph construction (each call to `train()`, `evaluate()` etc. reconstructs the graph). So it explicitly disables eager execution when invoked.

Is it possible for you to use your own training loop or use `tf.keras.Model.fit()` instead of using the `Estimator` API?

Comment: Yeah I guess I will need to find a workaround, I just thought there was a way to do it using Estimators as well. I will probably go for my own loop with metrics measured outside several `train()` calls for each 'epoch' of training.